# plotting shape of breed in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

In my model, I have 2 breeds drivers and bikers. Depending on the weather, they change shape into either a bike or a car. Here is an excerpt from my go function:

to go

```
ask drivers
 [
   ifelse temperature < 5
  [set shape "car"]
  [ move-drivers ]
 ifelse temperature > 5
  [set shape "bike"]
  [ move-drivers ]
]
```

I want to plot the number of cars and bikes at a given tick in my model, but I'm not sure what to write in the Pen update commands section of the plot. How can I plot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially count the drivers with the shapes of either a car or a bike:

`count drivers with [shape = "car" or shape = "bike"]`

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 2 breeds who can become either a bike or car at any moment, the pen updates commands that worked were:

plot count drivers with [ shape = "car" ] + count bikers with [ shape = "car" ]

plot count drivers with [ shape = "bike ] + count bikers with [ shape = "bike"]